# What steps should I follow to update AWS auto scaling alarms?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch

I am going to setup auto scaling on my AWS EC2 instance. After setup if I want to update auto scaling alarms, which is the best practice to do that? What are the steps should I be following?

I know that I can delete the alarms and recreate them using CloudWatch CLI. But do I need to make changes to auto scaling group while I am doing that? Or just deleting and re creating the  alarms will do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I created alarms in order auto scaling group>policy>alarm. So I can delete and recreate alarms independently. To delete policy i have to delete alarm using that policy.